# how to destroy all the data of the current page

Tags: javascript, charts, vue.js, setinterval

in my page , I have a real-time chart which updates every 3 seconds
I used setInterval(function(){...} , 3000) for make the chart updates.
but my problem is when I move to another page(by javascript) every thing are destroyed except my interval , so when I back to the chart page , it load every thing again and setInterval method works twice on every 3 seconds which makes duplicated points on mu chart.

this is destroy method
every line works except the myInterval one

```
    destroy()
    { this.num=0;
      this.c=0;
      this.startLive = false;
      clearInterval(this.myInterval); }
```

my problem appears just when I go to another page then back.

```
<template>
   ....
</template>
<script>
    var charts = [];
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                startLive: false,
                num: 0,
                c: 0,
                myInterval: null,
            }
        },
        methods: {
            initChart(dataProvieded) {
                charts[this.num] = AmCharts.makeChart("chart" + this.num, {...});
            },
            loadInitalData(limit) {
                this.fetchDatafromServer(limit).then((response) => { ...
                    this.initChart(data);
                    this.num++;
                    this.setInt();
                });
            },
            setInt() {
                this.myInterval = setInterval(function() { .... } , 3000);
            },
        }
        destroy() {
            this.num = 0;
            this.c = 0;
            this.startLive = false;
            clearInterval(this.myInterval);
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, `clearInterval` is the correct function to use. But apparently, it's either not finding your `this.myInterval`, or something else launches the interval again. I'm guessing it's not finding it. But with only this snippet of code, it's not easy to say. What is `this`, in the scope of this function? Where and how is `this.myInterval` defined? What do you get if you do a `console.log` of `this`, and `this.myInterval` (should be a number)? If you can, please provide a minimal example where we can reproduce the problem ourselves.

Comment: @blex I hope what I added will make the perception clearer

Comment: Could you show some code invoking `destroy()` in your example. And what do you mean by "moving to another page by javascript"?

Comment: @cepharum I didn't invoke destroy() it invoked by default. ammm I don't know how to say it , I use the same html page for both of them , only the view changes

Comment: Oh, I was missing the reference to vue.js ...

Answer (score 0):

It's strange, try to set `debugger;` before clearInterval to check variables.

By the way not all codepaths ok (looks like initializations doubled).

You should rewrite as

```
if (this.myInterval !== null) {
    clearInterval(this.myInterval);
    this.myInterval = null;
}
```

and add corresponding guard at setInt:

```
setInt() {
    if (this.myInterval === null ) {
        this.myInterval = setInterval(function() { .... } , 3000);
    }
}
```

May you need one interval per graph, please check your logic.